# How to make Netbeans recognize custom HTML attributes?

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-7

In netbeans (7.1.2) when adding a custom attribute to an HTML element, for example data-dismiss="modal I get a warning 'data-dismiss not allowed on element...'. Is it possible to add custom HTML attributes to Netbeans, making it aware of these attributes and not give a warning?

I've looked thoroughly through all menu options and configuration. I would expect something like 'add attribute to dictionary'